# Bronstein's lines of attack on the chessboard

Tags: famous-players

I remember reading as a child in a book by David Bronstein about an interesting piece of advice that he gave. He recommended to imagine the lines of movement for each piece all across the board as if not restrained by any intervening pieces. This is supposed to help to see all the tactical possibilities.

My question is to help me locate this quotation. I am also interested in any kind of remarks concerning this piece of advice.

Comment: Trying to find quotes or ideas like this would be a needle in a haystack since a lot of older books that are not in pdf format.

Comment: @Aaron The point of the question is to run into someone who actually knows the book in question and can simply grab it from their bookshelf and provide the quote.

Comment: Was the book written in English? Also do you have any idea what the book was about? Bronstein wrote a lot of books in his time, so any information to help narrow it down would help us help you.

Comment: @DTR I read it in Polish. The title was "self-tutor". There are two Russian originals with similar titles.

Answer (score 1):

This is actually a common piece of advice given to students of chess. Often chess blindness begins with not projecting your piece movement abilities beyond the first encountered piece in it's way. this helps to clear that deficiency away and begin to cultivate imagination and fantasy position ideas in your mind.

Comment: Nicely put and to the point.